# Does Linux Allow For Hiding Windows?

Tags: ubuntu, window-management

I'm currently a Windows user but I am looking to transition my main workstation to Linux like my servers. However I often use the [Hide Window Hotkey](http://www.elongsoft.com/hidewindow/hidewindow.htm) Tool, this tool allows you to select windows to hide then upon pressing a hotkey they are hidden from the task-bar but not closed, they can then be restored with another hotkey. I was wondering if there is an alternate tool for Linux. Or even an API to do such a thing, I'm a software developer and so I just need some guidance.

NOTE: This is not minimize, this is hiding the program from the task-bar.

Comment: there's other ways... run a window manager with no task bar :)  run a task with no GUI, stick it on a different virtual desktop...  trying to make linux work like ms-windows will often get you the worst of both worlds.

Comment: Switch to another workspace?

Comment: I'm sensing an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why do you want to hide the window? Is it to declutter your desktop/taskbar that have too many windows? Is it to hide NSFW activities when your boss came to your desk? Are you running a program that you don't need to interact frequently but want to keep always running in background? All these has different solutions in Linux.

Comment: Thank you Jasen and DK Bose that just might work for me. Lie Ryan I often use it to hide my active windows when I leave my PC, sort of like your boss scenario, just this is for my home PC.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they're called "window rules" and most popular window managers (Compiz, Kwin, Xfwm, etc.) implement them in some manner.

Compiz requires you to install an unofficial "compiz plugins" package, [KWin](https://userbase.kde.org/KWin_Rules) includes them as part of a standard installation, while Xfwm sets them in a config file.

Comment: How can I set window rules for Compiz to hide window using hotkey?